# How to can a fragment in TabActivity from AppActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am novice and trying to develop some app in my mind. Stuck with below error.

I have a main tabbed activity. 1st Tab is Add Record(Fragment), 2nd tab is Tracker( Fragment)of the added record. This Tracker have a filter button. When i click on Filter, Filter activity is opened which contains expandable list items. User selects some criteria and apply filter. Here i want to navigate to FilterActivity to 2nd Tracker tab. How can i do this?

When i try below line, the application halts and shows `unfortunately your app has stopped error` and momentary i am navigating to my Tracker tab. How to avoid that error message?

```
Intent intent=new Intent(FilterActivity.this,ShowTrackerRecycler.class);
```

Here **ShowTrackerRecycler** is a **fragment** which extends Fragment.

Getting below error:
**java.lang.ClassCastException: com.aaa.bbb.ShowTrackerRecycler cannot be cast to android.app.Activity**

Comment: You can't navigate to fragment using startActivity() becuase as it's name includes it only starts activities and not fragments. Fragment is a kind of small part of activity which you can show in your activity. So, you can't open fragment directly. you have to open any activity and set fragment in it. I recommand you to read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) before proceeding with fragment. It will help you a lot in understanding fragments and also prevents you from getting common errors in fragment concept.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani, from a tabbed main activity can i invoke an activity? As i said i got some threads where they directly use Fragments for each tab. So i am in impression that we should be creating Fragments for each tab. How to call a activity in from MainActivity? I use code  public Fragment getItem(int position) { and a switch statement with case tab 1:   and tab2. How to should i can for an activity here?

Comment: Did my answer ever work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the activity that uses the tracker fragment. In that activity then load the fragment.

So create an intent leading to the TabActivity which holds the trackerFragment

Add data for the activity to know what to do:

`intent.putExtra("showTracker", true);`

Then when the TabActivity loads,

Check for the extra data and load the fragment based on the data:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null && bundle.getBoolean("showTracker")) {
    // LOAD TRACKER FRAGMENT
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I might b dumb understanding your logic, but as i said my ShowTrackerRecycler extends fragment i have onCreateView and onResume methods. Because i use fragment, getIntent() method works here?

Comment: @Uday you can use the fragment. You have to use it's parent Activity, which then will call the fragment

Comment: Can't use the Fragment I mean

Comment: @Uday does that make more sense?